# Is this sentence correct? Two gerunds

Tags: verb-forms, syntax

> **Being** a German **mastering** the English language and having to read specialist literature in both languages for business reasons, it is likely ....

I am referring especially to the first part of the sentence...

Comment: Are you refering to "Being... mastering..." or to "Being... having..."? (N.B.: I suspect it's the first case, as indicated by the bolded emphasis, but that emphasis was not made by the OP.)

Comment: Seems like it would read better if you didn't exclude  the "who is"... "Being a German who is mastering the English language..."

Comment: It's fine. The meaning is "As I am a German mastering the English Language ...". Mastering is a verb heading a non-finite clause functioning as postmodifier to the noun German. The entire sequence up to the comma is an adjunct. The subject of the sentence is "it".

Comment: I don't really see how the dupe matches this... the usage of the words is different and the gerunds are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Although this "rule" (it's not really a grammatical rule but a stylistic suggestion) is often broken by native speakers, you want an opening clause like yours to modify the subject of the main clause; your main clause begins with "it".

Also, you don't need **being**.

> As a German (who is) mastering the English language and having to read
>   specialist literature in both languages for business reasons, **I** ...

Here's an example of a "dangler":

> *As someone who likes good beer*, please have plenty of it in the
>   fridge when I come to visit.

Better:

> As someone who likes good beer, I hope to find plenty of it in the
>   fridge when I come to visit.

This might seem rather forward. Imagine you're saying it to your brother, and that you indulged his penchant for pepperoni pizza when he came to visit you.